# Do devices like firewalls or load balancers have IP addresses?

Tags: networking, ip, device

Until now I know all network devices have IP addresses because someone may want to send something to it. But no one wants to send a packet to a device like a firewall or load balancer, as they just connect networks. I wonder if they have an IP address or not.

Answer (score 0):

A firewall or loadbalancer will have an IP address as you need to direct the packets to either of the devices for it to work it's magic, if its a firewall then you will want to block outgoing or incoming traffic, if you have loadbalancers then you will want to let that decide which node behind the LB that is able to process the incoming request.

Answer (score 0):

Not always. Some proxy devices are just 'bumps in the wire'.